# TI-Basic Dialog show more text

Tags: messagebox, ti-basic

I have a program on my TI-89 Titanium that displays text.  It works fine until the text becomes too long, and I get "Error: Dimension".  How can I circumvent this, or perhaps split the text into multiple dialogs?

Here's an example:

`Text "A short string that fits."
Text "A very long string that will not fit on a normal dialog!"`

Comment: It would be very helpful if you could share your code and a bit more details of what you are doing?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest using the `Dialog`, `EndDialog` command as opposed to `Text`.  `Text` can simply handle one line of no more than 37 characters, but really usually much more than 30 characters will run off the dialing and be invisible.  The `Dialog`, `EndDialog` is *much* more robust, it can take a `Title` and multiple lines of `Text`, `Request`, and `DropDown`.  Here is an example:

```
:Dialog
: Title "Some title text"
: Text "Some informational text"
: Text "Another line of informational text"
:EndDialog
```

You can also, as mentioned above use `Request` and `DropDown` lines as well.

If you have a variable containing a string of variable length to display you can do something like this:

```
:"String that is too long to fit on one line."→txt
:Dialog
: Title "Some title text"
: Text left(txt,30)
: Text right(txt,dim(txt)-30)
:EndDialog
```

The `left(str,n)` will return the `n` leftmost characters of `str`, similarly `right(str,n)` will return the `n` rightmost characters of `str`.  `Dim(str)` will return the number of characters in `str`.

You can read more about `Dialog`, `EndDialog` [here](http://tibasicdev.wikidot.com/68k:dialog).